# Use key and secret from database to implement Facebook login in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-login, laravel-8, laravel-socialite

I am creating a multi vendor web application in which I need to implement `login with Facebook` for customers. vendor can have their own domain or sub-domain and also own customers. In the website, I have implemented Facebook login by using env variables. the code is below.

Routes for facebook login

```
Route::get('auth/facebook', 'FacebookController@redirectToFacebook');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'FacebookController@handleFacebookCallback');
```

In config/services.php

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL'),
],
```

Facebook Controller function

```
public function redirectToFacebook()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleFacebookCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        $user_name = $user->getName();
        $user_email = $user->getEmail();
        $facebook_auth_id = $user->getId();
        /* other code */

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->route('login')->with(['error' => "facebook login failed."]);
    }
}
```

but I want to use **vendor's Facebook key and secret** which stored in database. How can I use dynamic variables here to implement the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure these packages should be included in your Controller

```
use Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager;
use Socialite;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider;
```

Use below code in your controller

```
public function redirectToFacebook(Request $request)
{
    $fb = $this->configDriver($request);
    return $fb->redirect();
}

private function configDriver(Request $request, $domain = '', $driver = 'facebook')
{
    $config['client_id'] = 'your_client_id';
    $config['client_secret'] = 'your_client_secret';
    $config['redirect'] = 'your_redirect_url';
    return Socialite::buildProvider(FacebookProvider::class, $config);
}

public function handleSocialCallback(Request $request, $domain = '', $driver = 'facebook')
{
    $usr = $this->configDriver($request)->stateless()->user();
    $name = $user->getName();
    $email = $user->getEmail();
    $facebook_id = $user->getId();
    /*save data in db*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been implemented using Laravel Socialite.

```
https://github.com/jd-patel/laravel-social-login
```